# Function checking valid input, loop repeating continuosly

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code and I cant get out of the 'while' loop in 'elegir()' function. When input is bad it keeps looping forever. I know that I can accomplish it  with if else conditionals, but I wanna know if it is possible to make it run with 'while'. Thanks.

```
Code here:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int const strsize = 100;
struct bop {
char fullname[strsize]; // real name
char title[strsize]; // job title
char bopname[strsize]; // secret BOP name
int preference; //89 0 = fullname, 1 = title, 2 = bopname
};
char elegir(); 
using namespace std;
int main(){

bop miembros[3] = {
{   
"Luciano",
"Doctor",
"Zahyr",
1
},
{
"Sabrina",
"Licenciada",
"Mumu",
2
},
{
"Andres",
"Verdulero",
"Uruguayo",
0
}
};

cout
    << "Elija como desea que se muestren los miembros de la 'Orden':" <<     endl
    << "a) Por nombre   b) Por titulo\n" 
    "c) Por nombre secreto  d) Por la eleccion del miembro\n";
char eleccion;

eleccion = elegir();
    while (eleccion == 'a' || eleccion == 'b' || eleccion == 'c' || eleccion    == 'd'){
        switch (eleccion){

        case 'a' : cout << "Mostrando miembros por 'Nombre':\n";
            for (int x=0;x<3;x++){  
                    cout    << miembros[x].fullname << endl; 
            }; break;
        case 'b' : cout << "Mostrando miembros por 'Titulo':\n";
            for (int x=0;x<3;x++){  
                    cout    << miembros[x].title << endl; 
            }; break;
        case 'c' : cout << "Mostrando miembros por 'Nombre secreto':\n";
            for (int x=0;x<3;x++){  
                    cout    << miembros[x].bopname << endl; 
            }; break;
        case 'd' : cout << "Mostrando miembros por preferencia del miembro:   \n";
            for (int x=0;x<3;x++){  
                     if ( miembros[x].preference == 0 )
                         cout << miembros[x].fullname << endl;
                     else if ( miembros[x].preference == 1 )
                         cout << miembros[x].title << endl;
                     else 
                         cout << miembros[x].bopname << endl;
            }; break;


        }
        cin
            >> eleccion;
    }



return 0; 
}
char elegir(){
char e;
cin
    >> e;
cin.clear('\n');
while (e != 'a' || e != 'b' || e != 'c' || e != 'd'){
    cout << "Eleccion incorrecta, elija nuevamente\n";
    cin
        >> e;
    cin.clear('\n');
}
return e;
}
```

Comment: Please run it through debugger. That's the best way to learn.

Comment: when input is valid it gets stuck in the while forever too...

Comment: the program is working well except now that I added the function to check input, it get stuck in the loop

Comment: No errors no warnings in debugger

Comment: Debuggers aren't for errors or warnings - they are used to step through the program and stop on various lines of code so you can evaluate the variable values and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with advice from The Dark answer, you also need `cin.clear()` before asking for input.

```
//main()    
cin.clear();       <-- include this line
cin >> eleccion;


//Similarly in elegir()
char elegir(){
    char e;
    cin >> e;
    cin.clear('\n');
    while (e != 'a' && e != 'b' && e != 'c' && e != 'd'){
    cout << "Eleccion incorrecta, elija nuevamente\n";
    cin.clear();    <-- include this line
    cin >> e;
    cin.clear('\n');
  }
return e;
}
```

Including `cin.clear()` clear the error flag which prevents infinite loop. Here is a tutorial which might help you understand in detail as it includes examples

http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student1.html

Comment: ok, corrected that, but now it continues to loop showing the data in cases

Comment: check updated answer. either include cin.clear() in main function before cin >> eleccion or just call eleccion = elegir(); I would do the latter as you already have the function asking for user input

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
while (e != 'a' || e != 'b' || e != 'c' || e != 'd'){
```

what happens if `e` is 'a'?

```
e != 'a' is false
e != 'b' is true
e != 'c' is true
e != 'd' is true
```

so your while test evaluates to

```
(false || true || true || true)
```

because you are using `||` this evaluates to

```
true
```

Solution - don't use `||` (or) here, use `&&` (and)

Comment: ok i see, so dumb of my part, I done that but now it shows me selection (case 'x') forever!! it was working well =/

Comment: Still looping forever on valid o invalid input